# Using Openflights database in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I would like to have a shapefile with the airports position and the routes of the planes I've found [Openfilghts](http://openflights.org/data.html) but I can't use it in QGIS.

Seems that the format of the DB `.dat` is not supported by QGIS.

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Despite the `.dat` extension it seems to me that this is CSV format (albeit without the field names). From the website that you linked to:

> To download the current data dump from SourceForge as a very
>   straightforward CSV (comma-separated value) file, suitable for use in
>   spreadsheets etc, simply click below

I tested it with the first dataset from the website ([airports](https://sourceforge.net/p/openflights/code/HEAD/tree/openflights/data/airports.dat?format=raw)) using QGIS 2.0.1 on Ubuntu machine. 
Opens without any issues using 'Create layer from delimited text file'.

Detailed instructions on how to do that are in the [manual](https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html) (bottom of the page).

For airport data - choose `field_8` as `X` field and `field_7` as `Y` field. And `WGS 84` as coordinate system:

[image]

Enjoy:

[image]